# Error 1193 when following 'employees database' install tutorial with MySQL 5.7.11

Tags: mysql

I downloaded and installed a vanilla instance of MySQL 5.7.11 (that's the version it reports when I run `> mysql -v`).  The instance is up and running.

Then I tried to follow the seemingly simple tutorial here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-installation.html

When I get to the step to run: `mysql -t < employees.sql` it fails, giving the error:

```
ERROR 1193 (HY000) at line 38: Unknown system variable 'storage_engine'
```

The `employees.sql` file is configured as instructed in the tutorial with the default setting.  How do I fix this error?

Note: I'm performing all steps as `root` in MySQL, and the system is Win10 if that has any bearing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tutorial hasn't been updated to reflect changes in recent MySQL versions. From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_storage_engine)

> This variable is deprecated and was removed in MySQL 5.7.5. Use `default_storage_engine` instead.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone cares to know the fix without finding the updated archive it's relatively simple:

1. Open the employees.sql file in your editor of choice
2. Edit lines 38 and 44

   ```
   // change line 38 from:
   set storage_engine = InnoDB;
   // to:
   set default_storage_engine = InnoDB;

   // change line 44 from:
   select CONCAT('storage engine: ', @@storage_engine) as INFO;
   // to:
   select CONCAT('default storage engine: ', @@default_storage_engine) as INFO;
   ```
3. Save employees.sql, then open a console window and navigate to the `employees_db` folder. Execute the following command from the prompt and your all set.

`c:\employees_db>c:\Path\to\MySql\bin\mysql.exe -u username -p < employees.sql`

Answer (score 1):

```
[root@001 employees_db]# vim employees.sql

set **default_storage_engine** = InnoDB;

-- set storage_engine = MyISAM;

-- set storage_engine = Falcon;

-- set storage_engine = PBXT;

-- set storage_engine = Maria;



select CONCAT('storage engine: ', @@**default_storage_engine**) as INFO;
```

Two changes needed ： default_storage_engine

Answer (score 0):

Updated db is available in https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db

It has the fix for MySQL 5.7.x

Answer (score 0):

no its not fix in a new version... I got the same error:
ERROR 1193 (HY000) at line 38: Unknown system variable 'storage_engine'

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)